# RxJava - use variables of a different types (results of a multiple chain operators) within "subscribe" lambda

Tags: android, kotlin, rx-java, observable, rx-java2

I'm trying to rewrite following rx-code in such way to remove a subscription within another subscription and to make code look more idiomatic:

```
 private fun foo() {
        compositeDisposable.add(getApiDataObservable().subscribe({ result ->
            if (!result.isSuccess) {
                mutableLiveData.value = "errorMessage"
            } else {
                compositeDisposable.add(Observable.zip(firstObservable,
                        secondObservable,
                        BiFunction<FirstObject, SecondObject, Pair<FirstObject, SecondObject>>
                        { obj1, obj2 -> Pair(obj1, obj2) }
                ).subscribe({

                    //there I need to use result and pair values
                }, {
                    Timber.e(it)
                }))
            }
        }))
    }
```

I'm tried something like this:

```
private fun foo2() : Disposable {
      return  getApiDataObservable()
                .filter { result.isSuccess }
                .flatMap {
                    //it - result
                    Observable.zip(firstObservable,
                            secondObservable,
                            BiFunction<FirstObject, SecondObject, Pair<FirstObject, SecondObject>>
                            { obj1, obj2 -> Pair(obj1, obj2) })
                }.subscribe {
                    //it - Pair<FirstObject, SecondObject>
               // here I need both  - result and pair values
                },{ mutableLiveData.value = "errorMessage"}
    }
```

But I have a misunderstanding in a next point : how can I obtain both  - **result** value from the `getApiDataObservable()` and a **pair** from the `Observable.zip(..)` call within `subscribe`. 
First thought that comes to the mind : to store **result** value  in some variable and use it inside  `subscribe` lambda. but maybe it is possible to achieve in more elegant and *more-rx* way.

Comment: aren't you getting the results at the same time?

Comment: no,see  answers below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create wrapper around result like that

```
class CompoundResult(apiResult: Result, firstObject: FirstObject, secondObject: SecondObject)
```

and modify `foo2()` function

```
private fun foo2() : Disposable {
    return  getApiDataObservable()
        .flatMap {
            if(!it.isSuccess) {
                Observable.error(Throwable("errorMessage"))
            } else {
                Observable.zip(firstObservable,
                        secondObservable,
                        BiFunction<FirstObject, SecondObject, CompoundResult>
                        { obj1, obj2 -> CompoundResult(it, obj1, obj2) })
            }
        }.subscribe ({
            //it - CompoundResult
            // here I need both  - result and pair values
        },{ mutableLiveData.value = it.localizedMessage })
```

}

Here i throw error, if `result` of api request is not success. That allow to trigger `onError()` of your subscriber

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can combine both `result` and `pair` when both are accessible an return a combined object. In the example below it is a `Pair<Result, Pair<FirstObject, SecondObject>>`, but maybe it is better to create a dedicated object.

```
private fun foo2() : Disposable {
      return  getApiDataObservable()
                .filter { result.isSuccess }
                .flatMap {
                    //it - result
                    Observable.zip(firstObservable,
                            secondObservable,
                            BiFunction<FirstObject, SecondObject, Pair<FirstObject, SecondObject>>
                            { obj1, obj2 -> 
                                val pair = Pair(obj1, obj2)
                                Pair(it, pair)
                            })
                }.subscribe {
                    //it - Pair<Result, Pair<FirstObject, SecondObject>>
                },{ mutableLiveData.value = "errorMessage"}
    }
```

Also note that the `.filter { result.isSuccess }` will not trigger further chain if the `result.isSuccess = false` and you will not receive any callback.